# mysql syntax error from mysql exported file

Tags: mysql

I exported a database (50 tables) from phpmyadmin, and I am attempting to import them via mysql command line using:

```
mysql -h localhost -D mydatabase --user=root --password=pass < /home/db.sql
```

However, I receive a syntax error in the sql file when I do this when I reach the 30th or so table.

```
..error..syntax to use near ''2006-01-25 1'
```

Now I can't go through all 1.5 million lines of sql (this is a big database) to correct this syntax which was produced by an export function. What are my options? Can you see any immediate problem?

The lines where this error occurs:

```
INSERT INTO `LINKS` VALUES(267, 581, 580, '2006-01-24 15:26:55');
>> INSERT INTO `LINKS` VALUES(268, 583, 582, '2006-01-25 17:06:39');
INSERT INTO `LINKS` VALUES(269, 585, 584, '2006-01-26 01:11:22');
```

It is on the 2nd line above, yet the error is not triggered on the almost identical 100 lines before that..? Could this be a memory issue or something else? The sql file is 300mb.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cPanel try exporting the database via the 'Backup Wizard' instead of phpMyAdmin

Comment: Also if you have shell access you could export via the command line